# yii framework models database access object

Tags: database, frameworks, yii

I want to use the database access objects to access a table in my database instead of doing active record since that takes a long time to load. if I use database access objets instead (calling createCommand, query, execute, etc), do i still need to create a model class for the table? if so what would be the parent class of this model class? My goal is to access/edit the table values using yii database access objects. I'm using YII FRAMEWORK. Or is it best to use a component? If so, when do you usually have to use components? I don't understand what components are for....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can create a generic class which has a member property of a CDbConnection. For that matter, you can just use CDbConnection, but you might end up creating a lot of connections that way.

```
class Foo
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){ $this->conn = 
                             new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password); }

    function runQuery($sql) {
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sqlStatement);
        return $command->query();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this class? inside the models directory?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your database settings in your [config/main.php](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration) file, you can also do:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

and if you need to reset the command:

```
$command = false;
```

If you create a custom class, you don't need to reference a Model or extend an existing class, your connection will use CDbConnection (by using the method above or calling it directly in your connection statement).

[this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) has pretty clear info on Yii's DAO.

As far as components go, they can mean different things - there are Yii's "core components", which are things like urlManager, user, db, etc. and can have their default properties set in the config/main.php file. Then there is the "components" directory which can be configured to autoload classes and "*contains components (e.g. helpers, widgets) that are only used by this application*." So you can put custom classes in there that you want available throughout your app.

Answer (score 1):

Components are used to make widgets.which is available through out the app.